# Behavior-Driven-Development is failing my expectations with PHPSpec

Tags: php, phpspec

I have the following class generated through PHPSpec:

```
class Consumer
{
   public function __construct($accesskey, $accessToken)
   {
      // TODO: write logic here
   }
}
```

When I test the constructor I get an error that it is missing Argument 1. Below is how I have written the behavior:

```
namespace spec\Zizy\Aggregator\Context;

use Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Contract\ContextContractInterface;
use Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Consumer;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

 class ConsumerSpec extends ObjectBehavior
 {
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
      $this->beConstructedWith( md5('samplekey'), md5('sampletoken') );
      $this->shouldHaveType(Consumer::class);
    }

    /**
    *  This spec describes how we would access our consumer directry
    */
    public function it_gets_access_token()
    {
       $this->getAccessToken()->shouldReturn(md5('sampletoken'));
    }
 }
```

Below is the error I get when running PHPSpec.

```
Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Consumer 21  - it gets access token
  warning: Missing argument 1 for Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Consumer::__construct() in C:\wamp64\www\spikes\src\Context\Consumer.php line 7
```

I have also tried to test my consumer through an interface but PHPSpec keeps telling me that it cannot find the interface but in a class context thus offer me an opportunity to create the class meanwhile it should actually be an interface.

How can I also write code through interfaces with PHPSpec?

Comment: I am aware of that but it felt appropriate to give a background like this so that anyone who comes to my rescue actually understands where I am coming from because to me an issue wouldn't just be PHPSpec but also the fact that I am using the library for the first time and maybe what needs to be fixed is my thought process than my code implementation. I hope that is a satisfying justification for you.

Comment: Fair. I will try to edit my question such that it is not cluttered with unnecessary information. Thanks

Comment: Not sure about it, but in the past I've had issues with the spec class name, try renaming `ConsumerBehavior` to `ConsumerSpec`

Comment: Hi @gfv even with th eclass name changed to `ConsumerSpec` I still get the same issue. I will spend a little more time researching this tool because I am interested in how it tackles development from ground up. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you paste the full class code you're trying to spec I might be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the constructor arguments for every example case. If you find that a bit too laborious, you can use [`let`](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/manual/let-and-letgo.html) to make preparations for before each example is run. For your case, something like this should work:

```
namespace spec\Zizy\Aggregator\Context;

use Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Contract\ContextContractInterface;
use Zizy\Aggregator\Context\Consumer;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class ConsumerSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let()
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith( md5('samplekey'), md5('sampletoken') );
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(Consumer::class);
    }

    /**
    *  This spec describes how we would access our consumer directry
    */
    public function it_gets_access_token()
    {
        $this->getAccessToken()->shouldReturn(md5('sampletoken'));
    }
}
```